# Closable panel in Senca touch Tab Panel as in Ext Js Tab Panel

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

We need to create a **Tab Panel** in Sencha Touch with the option to **close** individual panels of the tab panel.In sencha touch we can create a tab panel using following code:

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },

    items: [
        {
            title: 'Panel 1',
            html: 'Panel One'
        },
        {
            title: 'Panel 2',
            html: 'Panel Two'
        }
    ]
});
```

In Ext js we can create **closable tab panel** using the property   `closable:true` like this:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
        items: [{
            title: 'Tab 1',
            html: 'A simple tab',
          closable:true
        }, {
            title: 'Tab 2',
            html: 'Another one',
          closable:true

        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

So how we can achieve the same in sencha touch tab panel?

Comment: I know sencha touch, but never seen Ext.js closable tab. Can you describe the feature you need? Maybe setup a fiddle?

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/kgt .It shows the first panel is closable